# Computing gcd in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, greatest-common-divisor

I am teaching myself Java so I am doing labs from UC Berkeley [CS 61B](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~jrs/61b/lab/lab2/). I am trying to write a gcd method to make my toString method work.

the toString method prints a Fraction in non-reduced form.
Examine the code in the toString method.  It is calling another method called
gcd that computes the greatest common divisor (GCD) of two positive integers.
If this method worked correctly, toString would print Fractions in reduced
form. I have to rewrite the body of gcd so that it is
a recursive function that correctly computes the GCD.

Here is my toString method:

```
public String toString() {
    int thisGcd = gcd(numerator, denominator);

    return (numerator / thisGcd + "/" + denominator / thisGcd);
  }
```

My goal is to write the correct gcd function so that toString returns a fracyion in irreductible form. Here is what I wrote:

```
private static int gcd(int x, int y) {
    int div;
    if(x<0 || y<0){
        return -1;
    }
    else {

        if(x>y){
            div = y ;
        }
        else{
            div = x;
        }
        while( div !=0){
            if( (x % div==0 )&&(y % div == 0) ) {
                return div;

            }
            div --;

        }
    }

}
```

The instructions were about writing a recursive gcd function with the following pseudocode but I am not sure how to implement it exactly:

```
function gcd(a, b)
if b = 0
  return a
else
  return gcd(b, a mod b)
```

What is wrong with my gcd function ? How do I make mine work ? And how would I write the recursive function ?

Comment: The performance is way better for big numbers. Please Test your code with 10000000/9999999. Please Test your method and a suggested answer method with negativ numbers. e.g. -2/4, 2/-4 and -2/-4.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not follow the instructions?

```
private static int gcd(int x, int y) {
  if (y == 0) {
    return x;
  }
  return gcd(y, x % y);
}
```

This function is called tail-recursive because the last line is a recursive call. Tail recursive functions are very easy to transform into while loops:

```
private static int gcd(int x, int y) {
  while (y != 0) {
    int tempX = x;
    x = y;
    y = tempX % y;
  }
  return x;
}
```

As you can see the transformation makes the while loop predicate equal the predicate to call the recursive function and the contents of the while loop are just setting x and y to be the same as the input to the recursive function. This is true in general (see [wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call#Relation_to_while_construct)).

Answer (score 2):

Recursive function:

```
public int gcd(int a, int b)
{
 if(b == 0) return a;
 else return gcd(b, a % b);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are two versions, one short and concise:

```
    public static int gcd(int a, int b){
      return b == 0 ? a : gcd(b, a % b);
    }
```

Another one that is closer to your instructions:

```
    public static int gcd(int a, int b) {
      if (b == 0) 
        return a;
      else 
        return gcd(b, a % b);
    }
```

Where does your code come from? It doesn't look anything like the instructions.

These two versions are semantically exactly the same (I doubted for a second, because of strange behaviour of the ternary operator with autoboxing... But here is no place for autoboxing):

```
  public static int gcd(int, int);
    Code:
       0: iload_1
       1: ifne          8
       4: iload_0
       5: goto          15
       8: iload_1
       9: iload_0
      10: iload_1
      11: irem
      12: invokestatic  #10                 // Method gcd:(II)I
      15: ireturn

  public static int gcd_verbose(int, int);
    Code:
       0: iload_1
       1: ifne          6
       4: iload_0
       5: ireturn
       6: iload_1
       7: iload_0
       8: iload_1
       9: irem
      10: invokestatic  #13                 // Method gcd_verbose:(II)I
      13: ireturn
```

Comment: I would certainly hope so? Edit: oops... the first one is a compile error, `gcd` != `gcf`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `gcd` is horrible inefficient. Apart from that it's missing the final return-statement. Just assume, your input for is `x` = 0 and `y` = 1. it will pass through the first check for input < 0, 'div' is 0 and the whileloop is never executed. Now you're at the end of the method without any `return` statement. For the recursion:

```
public int gcd(int a , int b){
    return (b == 0 ? a : gcd(b , a % b));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You asked a three part question :

> What is wrong with my gcd function ? How do I make mine work ? And how
>   would I write the recursive function ?

others answered the last part very well, so I dont answer that part, but about your two other questions:

> What is wrong with my gcd function ?

the first thing is your code didnot return in every state, although logically it did, but java will give you compile error `error: missing return statement` so you need to add a return value to the end of your function if you just want it to work. But this will not fix your problems, your solution didnt return a right value for `gcd(0,a) = a` to fix this you just need to make some changes!

> How do I make mine work ?

This part is about making the changes, the below function is nearest thing to your answer that will work correctly:

```
private static int gcd(int x, int y) {
    int div;
    if(x<0 || y<0){
        return -1;
    }
    else {

        if(x>y){
            div = x-y ;    //to fix the problem for zero input
        }
        else{
            div = y-x;     //to fix the problem for zero input
        }
        while( div !=0){
            if( (x % div==0 )&&(y % div == 0) ) {
                return div;

            }
            div --;
        }
        return div;    //the return statement so you dont get compile error and fix problem of zero input.
    }
}
```

but why stop there? Your function is not time efficient at all, so lets make some changes:

```
private static int gcd(int x, int y) {
    int div;
    int a;
    if(x<0 || y<0){
        return -1;
    }
    else {
        if(x>y){
            div = y;
            a = x-y ;
        }
        else{
            div = x;
            a = y-x;
        }
        while( div !=0){
            if( (x % div==0 )&&(y % div == 0) ) {
                return div;
            }
            a = a - div;
            if(a<div){
                int temp = div;
                div = a;
                a = temp;
            }
        }
        return a;
    }
}
```

Although it is not what I want, but it is most efficient code that could make out of your code.